# Save image file to mySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I have an base64 encoded variable in my python script, it was originally an image. The images files will be around 1MB in size. I have two questions

**First:**

Should I decode this variable before saving it to mySQL database?

**Second:**

And this might depend on the previous answer. Should I save this as a `BLOB` or `TEXT`. I realize this might depend on what I am going to do with it later.
Later I am going to pull get this data from my database and display it in a website and in a iOS and android mobile app.

Comment: By far the most popular method is to store the image as a regular image file in the file system, and store the path to the image in the database. When storing the file itself within the database the most popular method is as a blob. The precise implementation and nuances are so widely discussed that I won't repeat them here except to say that advocates of one method over another tend to overstate their case. Both methods can work well; you just have to figure out which one is right for you.

Comment: @Strawberry great thanks, and if I was to store a path to the file would you just do that with `varchar`?